# Is it possible to define how much load should run on each slave machine when running jmeter with docker for distributed load testing

Tags: docker, jmeter

I am trying to run `Jmeter` with docker for distributed load testing, but I am not able to define load for each slave.

Comment: Could you add what have you tried? Some information to consider your question is not too broad?

Answer (score 0):

You can not because https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html :

"The same test plan is run by all the servers. JMeter does not distribute the load between servers, each runs the full test plan."